# Django - very slow query

Tags: python, django, database-optimization

I've made a module which parses xml file and updates or creates data in django db (pgsql).

When the data import/update is done I try to update some meta data of my objects.

I use django-mptt for tree structures and my meta-data updater is for creating such structures between my objects.

It's really really slow it takes about 1 second to populate parent with data from other foreignkey.

How do I optimise this?

```
for index, place in enumerate(Place.objects.filter(type=Place.TOWN, town_id_equal=True)):
    place.parent = place.second_order_division
    place.save()

    print index
    if index % 5000 == 0:
        transaction.commit()
transaction.commit()

transaction.set_autocommit(False)
for index, place in enumerate(Place.objects.filter(type=Place.TOWN, town_id_equal=False,
                                                   parent__isnull=True)):

    place.parent = Place.objects.get(town_id=place.town_id_extra)
    place.save()

    print index
    if index % 5000 == 0:
        transaction.commit()
transaction.commit()


class Place(MPTTModel):
    first_order_division = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=u"Województwo",
                                             related_name="voivodeships")
    second_order_division = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=u"Powiat",
                                              related_name="counties")
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
```

Edit:

I updated first function like this:

```
transaction.set_autocommit(False)
for index, obj in enumerate(Place.objects.filter(type=Place.COUNTY)):
    data = Place.objects.filter(second_order_division=obj, type=Place.TOWN, town_id_equal=True)
    data.update(parent=obj)
    print index
    transaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using loop you should do bulk updates [like](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once)

for first transaction you can replace your transaction with this Django query:

```
Place.objects.filter(type=Place.TOWN, town_id_equal=True).update(parent=F('second_order_division'))
```

For second transaction we can not apply bulk update because of again query on Place model.
for this you should do something to save hitting 'Place.objects.get(town_id=place.town_id_extra)' query each time in loop.

or can take help from this [blog](http://voorloopnul.com/blog/doing-bulk-update-and-bulk-create-with-django-orm/)

Answer (score -1):

Answering a more general question, one tactic to improve performance of almost any type of system is:

> Minimize interaction between the dynamic parts of your system

That's it: minimize interaction through HTTP requests, database queries, etc. In your case, you are doing multiple queries to your database that can be easily reduced to fewer (perhaps one or two).

Comment: Although that is an important notice, that is not answering the OP's question. This fact makes this a comment, not an answer. So it is better you add this as a comment and delete this answer, or update it to address what OP asks for.

Comment: Why is it not answering the question?

Comment: Because you are talking about *very basic concept of how to design a system*, OP asks *how he can __optimize his existing__ system*